# probability of a board containing a certain number of accountants

Tags: probability, statistics

A corporate board contains twelve members. The board decides to create a five-person Committee
to Hide Corporation Debt. Suppose four members of the board are accountants. What is the probability that the Committee will contain two accountants and three nonaccountants?

cant figure this one out

Comment: binomial distribution? why are you asking 2 questions in 1 minute on the same topic rather than wait for a hint on one of them and see if you can do the other on your own. this is homework right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\binom{12}{5}$ ways to choose the $5$ people from the $12$. We are expected to assume these choices are all **equally likely**. That is a very unreasonable assumption. It is simply not true that committees are chosen by tossing coins or dice.

But let's hold our noses and go on.  Call a choice **good** if it consists of $2$ accountants and $3$ others. There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to choose the $2$ accountants. For **every** such choice, there are $\binom{8}{3}$ ways to choose the $3$ others. So how many good choices are there?

Comment: so the good choices would be $$ \frac{\binom{4}{2} \binom{8}{3}}{\binom{12}{5}} $$
would this be correct?

Comment: You have written down the probability correctly. The number of good choices is $\binom{4}{2}\binom{8}{3}$.

Comment: this would equal to 62 / 792 which is 0.08 which is the probability that the Committee will contain two accountants and three nonaccountants? can someone concur

Comment: The denominator is right. The numerator isn't.

Comment: oops it will be 336 so the probability would be 336/792, now its right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. In your first comment, you correctly wrote that one should multiply $\binom{4}{2}$ and $\binom{8}{3}$. But when calculating, you pressed the $+$ button. It is safer to do it in one's head.

Answer (score -1):

Using the Hypergeometric distribution formular,
$$p(x) = {{k \choose x} {N-k \choose n-x} \over {N \choose n} }$$

$N=12$  , $n=5$ ,
$k=4$  ,
$x=2$  ,
$n-x=3$ (non-accountants) , $p(x) = 14/33$

Comment: Thanks for that